# Migrate .rdlc reports from one application to another

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, rdlc, windows, migrate

This might be a really easy question for the guru's in stackover flow but i am not sure how to approach it.

**Migrating from Desktop Application to Web Applicaiton**

**Used C# for Desktop Application**

**Used Asp.net for Web Application**

first i created the desktop application but due to the time constraint on installing it on several machines, i came up with the proposal to create a web app

**Issue**
there are several reports that i dont want to recreate, they are just too complicated and i had already created these reports for the Desktop application i want to basically copy that report and paste it into the web application and link that in in the reportviewer and just change the datasource which would save me the trouble of recreating. i tried creating one of the report manual but the layout got messed up on the browser.

Plz help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`WinForms.ReportViewer` can preview your rdlc using `DisplayMode.PrintLayout` but this is not possible with `WebForms.ReportViewer` where you basically always work with `DisplayMode.Normal`.

If exporting your web rdlc to `PDF` solves the layout problem, try display your report directly in this format.